# How can I draw a linerenderer line between two vector3 positions using the mouse left button click?

Tags: unity, c#

This code is drawing a line but it's not drawing it on the camera in front of the camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DemoScriptDraw : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Vector3> _positions = new List<Vector3>();
    private LineRenderer lr;

    private void Start()
    {
        lr = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 pos = Input.mousePosition;
            pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, lr.transform.position.z));
            _positions.Add(pos);

            if (_positions.Count == 2)
            {
                SpawnLineGenerator(_positions[0], _positions[1], Color.red);
            }
        }
    }

    void SpawnLineGenerator(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();

        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        myLine.AddComponent<EndHolder>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.useWorldSpace = true;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
    }
}
```

The result is that the line is seen in the scene view window but not in the game view window:

[image: line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```cs
pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, lr.transform.position.z));
```

you're using the Z position of the camera itself.

Keep in mind that the Z returned by the method is the distance from the plane normal to the camera forward direction and the Z parameter itself.

In your case, since `Camera.main.position.z` is -10, and you pass -10 as the Z parameter, the Z returned will be -20.

If you position the camera to Z = 10, then the method will return Z = 20, etc.

So, if the camera is in Z = -10 and the new line renderer has both positions set to Z = -20, it will be behind the camera frustum and not rendered.

Comment: I see I could also change the GameObject myLine = new GameObject(); position to be in front of the camera. But how can I make it automatic to be always in front the camera ? Either the lr position or the myLine position.

Comment: If your camera never moves, then you can simply provide a specific Z parameter to `ScreenToWorldPoint`, for example if you want to create the LR in Z =35, just pass 45 as Z, such that 45-10=35. Or just modify the `pos.position.z` as you wish before adding it to the list.